# Excel::Writer::XLSX set_optimization() only writes numeric data

Tags: perl, excel, export-to-excel, xlsx

I am using the Excel::Writer::XLSX perl module to export to Excel. It is working great except large exports take a long time. However, when I add $workbook->set_optimization(); I only get numeric data in my .xlsx file.

I have tried using both $worksheet->write() and $worksheet->write_string() but any fields that have a string rather than a number are being left out of the export when I use $workbook->set_optimization();

If I use the older Spreadsheet::WriteExcel module it works just fine but the file size of the export is substantially larger, 24MB vs. 7MB

Here is the code for creating the header row:

```
# Create a new workbook
my $workbook = Excel::Writer::XLSX->new($file_path);

$workbook->set_optimization();

my $worksheet = $workbook->add_worksheet();
# insert the header row
my $header_cnt = 0;
foreach my $header_cell (@header_values){#loop through each header column and add it to the sheet
    # print $header_cell." - ".$header_cnt."\n";
    # $worksheet->write_string("0", $header_cnt, "test");
    $worksheet->write_string("0", $header_cnt, $header_cell);
    $header_cnt++;
}

$workbook->close() or die "Error closing file: $!";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There shouldn't be a problem writing numbers or strings in `set_optimization()` mode. In fact there are [several test cases just like that](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/JMCNAMARA/Excel-Writer-XLSX-0.65/t/regression/optimize01.t).

I ran a variant of your program with some sample data and the output showed up correctly.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use Excel::Writer::XLSX;

my $workbook = Excel::Writer::XLSX->new('test.xlsx');
$workbook->set_optimization();

my $worksheet = $workbook->add_worksheet();


my @header_values = ( 1, 2, 3, 'foo', 'bar', 6, 7 );
my $header_cnt    = 0;

for my $header_cell (@header_values){
    $worksheet->write(0, $header_cnt, $header_cell);
    $header_cnt++;
}

$workbook->close();
```

[image: example output]

Note that the strings are aligned to the left and the numbers to the right which indicates that Excel is treating them as string and numeric data.

Also, if you use the `write_string()` method then you are going to get a string in either case.

The issue that you are encountering may be that in optimization mode you need to write data in row-column order, i.e., each row and each column in that row must be written sequentially.

For example, if you added these lines after the for loop the second data won't show up in optimization mode:

```
$worksheet->write('A2', "This is fine");
$worksheet->write('A1', "I'm too late.");
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply.  I copied your code and ran it and only the numbers showed up in the export. When I comment out set_optiomization(); then I get all of the data (the numbers and the strings.)

Comment: What are you using to view the output file? I didn't shop the screenshot. The data does show up in Excel. :-)

Comment: I have been using Numbers on OS X to look at the files. However, I just opened the file in Excel on Windows and the data is all there.

Comment: Interesting. The set_optimisation() mode uses Excel's inline strings instead of shared strings. Both conform to the ECMA-376 OpenXML specification. So, I guess we could say this is an issue with Numbers (I'll test later).

Comment: I'm actually using Numbers 08, so that might be part of the issue. Thanks for your help and thanks for the excellent module.

Comment: I tried with Numbers 09 and it has the same behaviour as 08: the strings are not visible. Also mentioned [here](https://github.com/harvesthq/simple_xlsx_writer).

Answer (score 0):

To reduce memory usage set_optimization() method is used and it will not restrict the data to be numeric. It can handle both numeric as well as string.

And to loop through each row

```
foreach my $record (@records){
  $row++;
  $col = 0;

  foreach my $data (@{$record}){
      $worksheet->write($row,$col,$data);       
      $col++;
  }
}
```

Refer "Write_largeData_XLSX.pl" from this link https://github.com/AarthiRT/Excel_Writer_XLSX for more details.